# Is there a sample-less cubemaps in vulkan?

Tags: glsl, textures, vulkan, sampling

In my game-engine all the static textures are bounded on an one big descriptor set(I using dynamic indexing for that), and now i also want to bind a cube-texture at orbitrary index inside this descriptors array.
All my textures bounded saperatly without any sampler(I am using glsl-extention named "GL_EXT_samplerless_texture_functions" for that).

Is there a way in vulkan-glsl to implement a cube-sampling of sample-less texture?

Sorry about my English.

Comment: Is this "one big descriptor set" an array of `texture2D`? If so, then they are... `texture2D`s, not `textureCube` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `texelFetch` functions are intended for accessing a specific texel from a given mipmap level and layer of the image. The texture coordinates are explicitly in "texel space", not any other space. No translation is needed, not even denormalization.

By contrast, accessing a cubemap from a 3D direction requires work. The 3D direction must be converted into a 2D XY texel coordinate and a face within the cubemap.

Not doing translations of this sort is the entire point of `texelFetch`. This is what it means to access a texture *without* a sampler. So it doesn't make sense to ever `texelFetch` a cubemap (and only the `texelFetch` functions are available for accessing a texture without a sampler).

So if you want to access a cubemap, you want one of two things:

1. You want to pass a 3D direction, which gets converted into a 2D coordinate and face index.

   You need a sampler for that. Period.
2. You have a 2D coordinate in texture space and a face index, and you want to access that texel from the texture.

   In this case, you're not accessing a cubemap; you're accessing a *2D array texture*. Indeed, there is no such thing in Vulkan as a "cubemap image"; there is merely a 2D array image which has a flag set on it that allows it to be associated with cubemap image *views*. That is, a "cubemap" is a special way of accessing a 2D array. But you can just as easily create a 2D array view of the same image and bind that to the descriptor.

   So do that.

Comment: Thanks for you response. So I understand there is no direct easier way to do this, so I will build a map from directions to the face index manually. good idea.

Comment: @TheAntsMaster: Or you could just *provide a sampler*.